# Finding the modular inverse of $\alpha$ with respect of 26

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to prove that given a certain $\alpha$, its modular inverse with respect of 26 ranges between [0,25].

Can you give me an hint ?

Comment: All integers, whether or not they're anyone's inverse, will live in $[0,25]$ when you work mod 26.

Comment: To be more exact, all integers belong to an equivalence class $[a] = \{a + 26\Bbb Z\}$, and $a$ can be chosen to be in $[0, 25]$ if you like.

Comment: You can just try them all in a spreadsheet.  There will only be one when $a$ is coprime to $26$, so has no factors $2$ or $13$.  If the modulus is too large to try them all, the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) is what you need.

Comment: If you are attempting to prove that *every* natural $< 26$ occurs as an inverse then this statement is not true, because $a$ is invertible $\!\bmod n\iff \gcd(a,n)=1\ $ (by Bezout).

Comment: @Randall can you explain me why ?

Comment: Every integer is congruent to something mod 26:  just long-divide by 26 and take the remainder.